# Non existing GPO applying? WSUS

Tags: windows-server-2003, wsus

I recently took my WSUS server offline. In the mean time I want the clients to update from the internet until I get WSUS up again.

However, Windows Updates is tring to contact the old server and (obviously) failing to get new updates.

- I have updated the WSUS GPO to *disabled*.
- Checked DNS is resolving.
- Deleted WSUS GPOs.
- GPRESULT reports that policy is not being applied
- Run GPUPDATE /force
- No issues reported from DCDIAG

I delete the registry keys HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate

But the keys return after a reboot.

What else can I try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `rsop.msc` to see which policies are still being applied.

Comment: Argh! I want to kick myself. I had run this before but I wasn't thorough enough. I did find another gpo that also had wsus settings baked in. I had no idea this gpo even existed. I modifed the troublesome GPO. Thanks for the help!